# How to check "Allow Full Access" is granted since iOS 8.3 *from the container app*

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios8-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

Prior to iOS 8.3, the way to check whether "Allow Full Access" was granted to a keyboard extension was through the following code in the **container app**:

```
- (BOOL)isOpenAccessGranted{
   return [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
}
```

However, as comments on this popular SO answer [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472388/how-to-check-the-allow-full-access-is-enabled-in-ios-8) point out, since iOS 8.3, an app can read from shared group containers even if full access is not granted, so the above code always returns true. However, **write** permission is granted only if "Allow Full Access" is turned on.

I have tried listing out all of the pasteboards based on Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPasteboard/pasteboardTypes) on `UIPasteboard`, but it does not delineate which ones are accessible. Any insights on this is much appreciated.

Comment: General pasteboard should be accessible to all for read and/or write. Shared containers are a different thing. Are you trying to have an app write to pasteboard which can be used by keyboard? Can you explain the scenario you want to use it in?

Comment: Please take a look into this answer:

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/26088674/3317354][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26088674/3317354

Comment: Hi @Omar - yes, indeed I am trying test whether the shared container could be writable (granting "full access" on an iOS keyboard allows it to be writable and readable, so one can read data from the container app based on what's saved from the keyboard). Previously `generalPastboard` would have sufficed.

Comment: Please see "By default, a keyboard has no network access and cannot share a container with its containing app. To enable these things, set the value of the RequestsOpenAccess Boolean key in the Info.plist file to YES." in  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html and the available options when it is set to On https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW3

Comment: Thanks for the follow up @Omar. These options, such as `RequestOpenAccess` and the configuring the App Group has already been done in my project (based on the links that you provided). What I am asking is, once this is configured, how do I, via the containing app, detect whether the user has turned on sharing of data between the container and its containing app. I can then provide different functionalities depending on the user's action.

Comment: Thanks for the link @teamnorge. I have tried the code but it still has not worked.

Comment: Full Access is an atomic permission. It is either yes or no. If it is enabled you will have read and write permission. See link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472388/how-to-check-the-allow-full-access-is-enabled-in-ios-8. If you are trying to make it work in an app group then you can test it by explicitly testing access to the app's sandbox. Otherwise it would be a security concern.

Comment: @Omar if you see the linked SO question you supplied, it's the exact same one as I referenced in the body of my question. I have consulted that question, and the problem is that the answer no longer works since iOS 8.3, hence my asking the question here. In other words, how do I explicitly test access to the app's sandbox.

Comment: I just confirmed that the code [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] works on device and not on simulator(nil when no Full Access and not nil when Full Access is allowed). Can you try it on device. I am running iOS 8.3.

Comment: @Omar thanks for trying. I have tried it on a device running iOS 8.4, and unfortunately it is not working. The exact code are as you see above in the question body, and its ran when executing `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84513/discussion-between-omar-and-daspianist).

Comment: @daspianist did you solve your trouble? i'm looking for answer too

Comment: @TomSawyer Just saw this Tom. Unfortunately no solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my currently working / deployed implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"keyboard has full access? %@", ([self validateKeyboardHasFullAccess] ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
}

- (BOOL)validateKeyboardHasFullAccess {
    return !![UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! This works great when checking full access from inside the keyboard, but I was wondering if there is also a way to do so from the container app.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 8.4 the `UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()` is `nil` if Full Access is not allowed. 
Try removing keyboard and container app + `clean and build` app, before testing again. Should work fine.

Comment: I tried above code but even if  "Full Access" not given it returns Yes.